# MVVMLight UserControl View Model-Create new Instance of User control for each view

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have a user control of list of Patients which I use in other Views. However when I choose one of the Patients, the selection is propagated to all the views containing an instance of the user control. How can I make each view instantiate a new instance of the user control for each view?
I am using c#

Comment: Please post code/XAML to show how you're currently dealing with your user control.

Comment: I think we will need to see code/XAML as ken2k stated but from what you have said it sounds like your view of the siutuation is the wrogn way round. "How can I make each view instantiate a new instance of the user control for each view?", are you sure you don't want new instances for each user control. As in you either want a shared model for all views which means that the behaviour you're seeing makes sense or you need a instance of the model binding to the user control for each control.

Comment: see the solution offered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing from what you stated, I'd assume that you returning a static instance of you PatientViewModel from you locator. To solve this make sure that when the property is called a new instance of the view model is generated.

**Edit: Locator with different instantiation methods**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            //if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            //{
            //    // Create design time view services and models
            //    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    // Create run time view services and models
            //    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            //}

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

      public MainViewModel StaticMain
      {
          get
          {
              return _staticMain ?? (_staticMain = new MainViewModel());
          }
      }
      private static MainViewModel _staticMain;


      public MainViewModel NewMain
      {
          get
          {
              return new MainViewModel();
          }
      }

      public MainViewModel NewIocMain
      {
          get
          {
              return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
          }
      } 

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

1. The `Main` property uses Lauent's `SimpleIoc` container to create an instance. One of the properties of this container is, that it treats every type as singleton. Thus if you use this VM generation method you will share the VM throughout the views.
2. The `StaticMain` property does much the same, but instead of using Laurent's container it holds a static instance of the VM which is also shared between the views.
3. The `NewMain` property creates a new VM upon every call, therefore, the VM is not shared between the views.
4. The `NewIocMain` property also creates a new VM upon every call and the VM is, therefore, not shared between the views. However, the `SimpleIoc` container holds a reference to the instance created. It does not release this instance automatically and you have to call `SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(key)` with the key you used for creation (the Guid) to remove the instance from the container once you no longer need it.

Instead of using the `SimpleIoc` you obviously can opt to use another IOC Container - such as Unity for example - that allows you greater control how your instances are created and how long they live. Barring this, I'd opt for the `NewMain` approach given yor case.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using an IOC Container, in this case Unity in s/w development?