# MVVM light multiple instances of usercontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

How can I get multiple instances of a usercontrol without the viewmodel being shared? Each usercontrol (and thus viewmodel) should be an instance of its own.

I have read a solution in this question: [MVVMLight UserControl View Model-Create new Instance of User control for each view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362332/mvvmlight-usercontrol-view-model-create-new-instance-of-user-control-for-each-vi) but I cannot get it to work!

I have a listview and a tabcontrol. When I click an item of the listview a new tab must be created with as content the usercontrol which holds information from the selected listitem. The problem is that when selecting multiple items all the items contain the information from the last selected item.

This is my viewmodellocator:

```
        public DossierDetailViewModel DossierDetail
    {
        get
        {
            return new DossierDetailViewModel();
        }
    }
```

And I call the new usercontrol like this:

```
        DossierDetailViewModel newDossier = new DossierDetailViewModel();
        newDossier.TabName = SelectedDossier.Omschrijving;
        this.OpenDossiers.Add(newDossier);
        Messenger.Default.Send<DTO.Dossier.Dossier>(SelectedDossier, "SetDossier");
```

**EDIT:**
Is there no one who can help me or put me in the right direction? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this problem can be found here: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/577555